# RDF/SKOS concept hierarchy as Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, rdf

In Python, how do I turn RDF/SKOS taxonomy data into a dictionary that represents the concept hierarchy only?

The dictionary must have this format:

```
{ 'term1': [ 'term2', 'term3'], 'term3': [{'term4' : ['term5', 'term6']}, 'term6']}
```

I tried using RDFLib with JSON plugins, but did not get the result I want.

Comment: What did you try "using RDFLib with JSON plugins"?  In what way was the result not what you wanted?

Comment: What is the format you want?  The first entry looks like "class : [direct-subclass-1, direct-subclass-2]" with no nested entries, (e.g., from the second entry, we know that term3 has sub-terms, but they're not listed in the first entry.  In the second entry, however, term4's entry is nested.  What's the format that you want?  If it's just `{ subclass_i : [ direct-subclass_ij ] ... }`, that shouldn't be too hard with any library that lets you query for subclasses.

Comment: As Joshua says, you need to add more context and define your goals more precisely. It would help if you added the SKOS that should be transformed into the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a Python user, and I haven't worked with RDFLib, but I just pulled the SKOS and vocabulary from the [SKOS vocabularies page](http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/vocabs).  I wasn't sure what concepts (RDFS or OWL classes) were in the vocabulary, nor what their hierarchy was, so I ran this a SPARQL query using Jena's ARQ to select classes and their subclasses.  I didn't get any results.  (There were classes defined of course, but none had subclasses.)  Then I decided to use both the SKOS and SKOS-XL vocabularies, and to ask for properties and subproperties as well as classes and subclasses.  This is the SPARQL query I used:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?property ?subproperty ?class ?subclass WHERE { 
  { ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?class }
  UNION 
  { ?subproperty rdfs:subPropertyOf ?property }
}
ORDER BY ?class ?property
```

The results I got were

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| property                | subproperty             | class           | subclass                                  |
===================================================================================================================
| rdfs:label              | skos:altLabel           |                 |                                           |
| rdfs:label              | skos:hiddenLabel        |                 |                                           |
| rdfs:label              | skos:prefLabel          |                 |                                           |
| skos:broader            | skos:broadMatch         |                 |                                           |
| skos:broaderTransitive  | skos:broader            |                 |                                           |
| skos:closeMatch         | skos:exactMatch         |                 |                                           |
| skos:inScheme           | skos:topConceptOf       |                 |                                           |
| skos:mappingRelation    | skos:broadMatch         |                 |                                           |
| skos:mappingRelation    | skos:closeMatch         |                 |                                           |
| skos:mappingRelation    | skos:narrowMatch        |                 |                                           |
| skos:mappingRelation    | skos:relatedMatch       |                 |                                           |
| skos:narrower           | skos:narrowMatch        |                 |                                           |
| skos:narrowerTransitive | skos:narrower           |                 |                                           |
| skos:note               | skos:changeNote         |                 |                                           |
| skos:note               | skos:definition         |                 |                                           |
| skos:note               | skos:editorialNote      |                 |                                           |
| skos:note               | skos:example            |                 |                                           |
| skos:note               | skos:historyNote        |                 |                                           |
| skos:note               | skos:scopeNote          |                 |                                           |
| skos:related            | skos:relatedMatch       |                 |                                           |
| skos:semanticRelation   | skos:broaderTransitive  |                 |                                           |
| skos:semanticRelation   | skos:mappingRelation    |                 |                                           |
| skos:semanticRelation   | skos:narrowerTransitive |                 |                                           |
| skos:semanticRelation   | skos:related            |                 |                                           |
|                         |                         | _:b0            | <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#Label> |
|                         |                         | skos:Collection | skos:OrderedCollection                    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It looks like there's not much *concept* hierarchy in SKOS at all.  Could that explain why you didn't get the results you wanted before?